# Installing PHP 5.2.17 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, php

I'm trying to install PHP 5.2.17 on Windows Server 2008 (running on a virtual pc). After accepting the license and clicking next, I get the following error message:

---

**PHP 5.2.17 Setup**

Please Wait While The Installer Finishes Determining Your Disk Space Requirements.

[Return]

---

The dialog never closes. When I click Return, then Next to continue with the setup, the dialog is shown again. The server has 114 GB of free disk space.

What is the problem and how do I work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange: after I copied the setup kit to another folder (C:\ in my case) the setup suddenly worked. The setup kit was originally located in C:\users\administrator\downloads.